# Microsoft Access - Label Printing - each 10 labels to print vertically

Tags: label

Good day, I am having an issue, I need to print 3000 lables every 7 days and they are cut in to individual lables, at the moment they are printing in sequence 1,2,3,4,5,6...etc, so person wastes time to pick them up and put them in correct slots

Now what I need is that record Number 2 is printed on 2nd page, 3rd record on page 3 and like this 10 pages, my 11 record under is on 1st page just below  record number 1, record 12 is on page 2 under record number 2.....
So idea is that person can grab a stack of 10 record instead of taking them one by one, but I am not sure how can I do it=\ any Ideas?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: It is there is a Macro to assign numbers to data source so that it can be sorted to cause labels to print down columns, unfrotunately I am such a newb in VBA that I need help, the source I have for Word but not for access

Answer (score 0):

```
     ' Macro to assign numbers to data source so that it can be sorted to cause labels to print down columns
     Dim Message, Title, Default, labelrows, labelcolumns,
      i As Integer, j As Integer,
     k As Integer
     Message = "Enter the number of labels in a row"    ' Set prompt.
     Title = "Labels per Row"    ' Set title.
     Default = "3"    ' Set default.
     ' Display message, title, and default value.
     labelcolumns = InputBox(Message, Title, Default)
     Message = "Enter the number of labels in a column"    ' Set prompt.
     Title = "Labels per column"    ' Set title.
     Default = "5"    ' Set default.
     labelrows = InputBox(Message, Title, Default)
     ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns.Add
     BeforeColumn:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(1)
     ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(1).Range.Cut
     k = 1
     For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count - labelcolumns
     For j = 1 To labelrows
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(i, 1).Range.InsertBefore k + (j - 1) *
    labelcolumns
    i = i + 1
    Next j
    k = k + 1
    i = i - 1
    If k Mod labelcolumns = 1 Then k = k - labelcolumns + labelcolumns *
    labelrows
    Next i
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Sort FieldNumber:="Column 1"
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(1).Select
    Selection.Paste
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(1).Delete
```

this one I had was for word, unfortunately it didn't work exactly the way I need